# Implement the algorithm for this method ... int ClaculateDayOfYear(int year, int month, int day)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I am trying to find the number of days between dates and also check for leap years. I am new to programming and trying to implement this method in c# console application. Will appreciate your help?

Comment: Don't worry about being new to C#.  The language has nothing to do with the algorithm.  First, determine how you would figure this out on your own.  If you had only pencil and paper and had to show your work, what steps would you take to produce the desired output from the supplied input?  Then, once you have that algorithm, you can begin to encode it into C# one statement at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `DateTime.IsLeapYear(int)` to check if the year is leap year.

use `date1.Subtract(date2).Days` to find the number of days between dates.